# How can I trigger the copy constructor for data members?

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, copy-constructor

I tried this:

```
class cls1{
    public:
    cls1(){ cout << "cls1 constructor\n";}
    cls1 (cls1 & o){ cout << "cls1 copy constructor\n";}
};

class cls2{
public:
    cls2 () { cout << "cls2 constructor\n";}
    cls2 (cls2 & o){ cout << "cls2 copy constructor\n";}
};

class my_cls{ 
public: 
    cls1 o1;
    cls2 o2;
    my_cls(){ cout << "my_cls constructor\n";}
    my_cls(my_cls& o){ cout << "my_cls copy constructor\n";}    
};    

void f(my_cls o){}

int main(){
    my_cls p;
    f(p);
    return 0;
}
```

but the output is:

```
cls1 constructor
cls2 constructor
my_cls constructor
cls1 constructor
cls2 constructor 
my_cls copy constructor
```

I find this confusing since I've been told that for each member, the copy-constructor invokes the copy-constructor for that member, execpt for premitive types, when a bit-by-bit copy is made. (I expected cls1 and cls2's copy constructors to be called before my_cls's copy constructor)

Comment: This doesn't compile. What is `der`??

Comment: I replaced der with my_class because initially, my_class was derived from the first two. But I changed my mind about that, after I asked the question, though. Sorry about it. Thanks for the changes, Luchian Grigore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually:

```
der (der & o){ cout << "my_cls copy constructor\n";}
```

is equivalent to

```
der (der & o):o1(),o2(){ cout << "my_cls copy constructor\n";}
```

i.e. your copy constructor calls the default constructor of your class-type members.

To get it to behave like expected:

```
der (der & o):o1(o.o1),o2(o.o2){ cout << "my_cls copy constructor\n";}
```

To make it semantically correct:

```
der (der const& o)
```

Answer (score 5):

What you were told is only true for copy constructor generated by compiler.

If you are to write your own copy constructor you need to place copy c-tors of members and bases classes on initialization list, otherwise their default c-tors will be used.

In your example there are missing `: o1(o.o1), o2(o.o2)`:

```
der (der & o)
: o1(o.o1)
, o2(o.o2)
{ cout << "my_cls copy constructor\n";}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is just like an initialization list for a regular constructor

```
class my_cls{ 
public: 
    cls1 o1;
    cls2 o2;
    my_cls (){ cout << "my_cls constructor\n";}
    my_cls (my_cls & o) : o1(o.o1), o2(o.o2) { cout << "my_cls copy constructor\n";}    
};
```